# Bootstrap Popovers don't hide on click outside on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap popover over a span with two of the following code snippets. First one closes on the click outside the popover but the second one doesn't.
On android and web both popovers close properly, the issue only comes on iOS chrome and safari browsers.

First:

```html
<span class="txt">Some text<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="cursor: pointer;" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-html="true" data-placement="@if(Agent::isMobile()){{ "top" }}@else{{ "left" }}@endif" data-content="Some content here. <a href='#'>Tell me more.</a>"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" style="font-size: 14px; color: #d2d2d2;"></i></a></span>
```

Second:

```html
<span class="tag-tooltip" style="cursor: default;" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-content="tag text"><span class="label tut-label label-xs label-{{ $tag->type }}">tag name</span></span>
```

I have tried most of the solutions given here on other questions. but I am not able to get both to work the same. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this, for ios i worked with touchstart..! this works fine for me..try it once..! may be this will help you..!

```
$(window).bind("click touchstart",function() {
    $('#summaryTooltipContent').fadeOut(500); 
    //give an id that u want to close on touch
});
```